# SWIFT4 Send JSON decoded result to a class for processing

Tags: json, swift, class

I am following a tutorial which involves fetching JSON data and decoding it to an array and got this working and it creates an array 'user', see code:

```
fileprivate func fetchHomeFeed(){

    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/twitter/home"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

let stringdata = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, jsonErr) in

        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {

            let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(Users.self, from: data )
            let index: Int = user.users.count

            //print the names to check
            for index in 0...(index - 1) {
                print(user.users[index].name)
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
           print("Error serialising ", jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

The way the app is set up is that there is a class in another file called HomeDataSource, which needs this array to display users. Presently I have there a static array which works and displays the data in the app. Now this needs to be filled with decoded data from the function in fetchHomeFeed()

I have tried many ways but I can't get it to work and I like to stick to the setup with the HomeDataSource some it is organised code.

```
class HomeDatasource: Datasource {
let users: [User] = {

let User1 = User(name: "Frank", username: "@Loremipsum", bioText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", profileImage: UIImage(named:("profile_image.jpg")))
let User2 = User(name: "Ben", username: "@Loremipsum", bioText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", profileImage: UIImage(named:("profile_image.jpg")))

    return [User1, User2]
}()
```

I would like some tips or code to help me tackle this problem..

Comment: it's very important to track catch errors

Comment: What did you try, what is happening and what should happen. If there is an Error, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Your response is a dictionary of users and tweets , and you declare your User class with wrong keys ( you can get rid of tweets key if you would like to )

```
let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data )
self.users = root.users

struct Root: Codable {
    let users: [User]
    let tweets: [Tweet]
}

struct Tweet: Codable {
    let user: User
    let image: Image
    let message: String
}

struct Image: Codable {
    let width, height: Int
    let imageURL: String 
}

struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, username, bio: String
    let profileImageURL: String 
}
```